# How can I change the animation between tab switches with a bottomNavigationView?

Tags: android-architecture-navigation

I have just updated my code to use the latest 2.4.0-alpha05 for the navigation component and I have custom navigation between the multiple stacks and my main nav graph is like the documentation I found.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:startDestination="@+id/accounts"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav">
    <inclue app:graph="@navigation/accounts_tab_nav"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/contact_tab_nav" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/profile_tab_nav" />
</navigation>
```

Most of my stacks animate with a slide from right to left. It looks like that when I am on the second screen, in let's say the profile screen, and then switch to the first tab it triggers the `popEnter` en `popExitAnim` that are defined in the action that leads to the second screen in the profile tab. Like so:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profileMain"
    android:name="com.app.ProfileFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_profileMain_to_secondFragment"
        app:destination="@id/secondFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
</fragment>
```

But obviously I want tho use the (default) fade animation when switching tabs. So how should I do that?

And I would like to pop to the root of the stack when reselecting a tab. But I probably have to do that myself?

Comment: For now I am sticking to the extension functions. And the plus side is that it now has fragment safe state lifecycle so that is already a huge plus.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a workable solution? What extension functions are you using exactly? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't update so not sure if new version of the lib solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that seems to work for me, but I have to admit it feels a little bit hacky.

I have a public flag in my MainActivity:

```
var tabWasSelected = false
```

Then I remember if a tab item was selected in setOnItemSelectedListener

```
// always show selected Bottom Navigation item as selected (return true)
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->      
  // In order to get the expected behavior, you have to call default Navigation method manually
  NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)

  // set flag so that the fragment can call the correct animation on tab change in onCreateAnimation
  tabWasSelected = true

  return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
}
```

This will always select the item and navigate to the associated destination while maintaining multiple back stacks.

I then have created a Fragment class which all my other fragments inherit from. It simply overrides onCreateAnimation to set the correct animation. Here is what it looks like:

```
open class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    
    override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation? {
        val activity = requireActivity()
        if (activity is MainActivity) {
            if (activity.tabWasSelected) {
                if (enter) {
                    //flow is exit first, then enter, so we have to reset the flag on enter               
                    //in order that following animations will run as defined in the nav graph
                    activity.tabWasSelected = false
                    return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
                } else {
                    return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim)
                }
            }
        }
        //no tab was selected, so run the defined animation
        return super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim)
    }
}
```